# MDX: How to get the Total Sum of column in one more column

Tags: ssas, mdx

[image]

Here i have one attribute TotalPatientCnt values are (30,2013,39), I need TotalSum(2082) of the TotalPatientCnt in one more attribute.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [ProgramNames] AS [DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [ProgramKey]   AS [DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_Key 
MEMBER TotalPatientCnt AS [Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt] 
MEMBER MetricPercent AS [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt] * 1 / TotalPatientCnt * 100 ,format_string = '#,##.00' 
SELECT {  [ProgramKey] , 
          [ProgramNames] , 
          [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt] , 
          [TotalPatientCnt] , 
          [MetricPercent] } ON COLUMNS, 
Order (NONEMPTY([DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].[Program Key],
                [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt]),
      [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt],BASC) ON ROWS 
FROM [PopulationReportCube] 
WHERE ([DimReport].[Report Key].[Care Management Metric],
       [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20170930],
       [DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].[Health Plan Key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your rows set into the WITH clause:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [ProgramNames] AS 
  [DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [ProgramKey]   AS 
  [DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_Key 
MEMBER TotalPatientCnt AS 
  [Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt] 
MEMBER MetricPercent AS 
  [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt] * 1 / TotalPatientCnt * 100 ,format_string = '#,##.00' 
SET [RowsSet] AS
    Order (
      NONEMPTY([DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].[Program Key],
                [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt]),
      [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt]
    ,BASC)
SELECT {  [ProgramKey] , 
          [ProgramNames] , 
          [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt] , 
          [TotalPatientCnt] , 
          [MetricPercent] } ON COLUMNS, 
[RowsSet] ON ROWS 
FROM [PopulationReportCube] 
WHERE ([DimReport].[Report Key].[Care Management Metric],
       [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20170930],
       [DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].[Health Plan Key]);
```

Then create a new measure that spans all of that set:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [ProgramNames] AS 
  [DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [ProgramKey]   AS 
  [DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_Key 
MEMBER TotalPatientCnt AS 
  [Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt] 
MEMBER [Measures].MetricPercent AS 
  [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt] * 1 / TotalPatientCnt * 100 ,format_string = '#,##.00' 
SET [RowsSet] AS
    Order (
      NONEMPTY([DimPatientProgram].[Program Key].[Program Key],
                [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt]),
      [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt]
    ,BASC)
MEMBER [Measures].[TotalCnt] AS 
  SUM(
    [RowsSet]
    ,[Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt] 
  )
SELECT {  [ProgramKey] , 
          [ProgramNames] , 
          [Measures].[ProgramPatientKeyCnt] , 
          [TotalPatientCnt] ,
          [Measures].[TotalCnt], 
          [MetricPercent] } ON COLUMNS, 
[RowsSet] ON ROWS 
FROM [PopulationReportCube] 
WHERE ([DimReport].[Report Key].[Care Management Metric],
       [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20170930],
       [DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].[Health Plan Key]);
```